# GA BigQuery - Users who bought product x also bought products abc then filter only list complete transacitons where x was part of a transaction

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

The following BigQuery SQL will retrieve all other products purchased for a customer (fullVisitorId) who bought a product named "Elephant" and with a category of "Animals".

Now here is the problem. If a the same customer (fullVisitorId) makes two orders within the same date range. Let's say he or she buys a product named "Tiger" in one transaction plus other products then Tiger and those products will show up as a related product too if he or she made a similar order a day before or later the same day buying Elephant because my query is using the fullVisitorId. In other words one fullVisitorId can have 1 or more transactionIDs. One transaction have the same transactionId for every product purchased for the current transaction.

So does anyone know how I can make additional filtering at the end to only show related products with the same transactionId when the primary product Elephant was purchased and ignore all others that with a different transactionID?

```
SELECT hits.product.productSKU AS other_purchased_products_sku,
       hits.product.v2ProductName AS other_product_name,
       hits.product.v2ProductCategory AS other_prod_category,
       COUNT(hits.product.productSKU) AS quantity,
       hits.transaction.transactionId AS trans_id,
       fullVisitorId
FROM
  ( SELECT fullVisitorId,
           hits.product.productSKU,
           hits.eCommerceAction.action_type,
           hits.product.v2ProductName,
           hits.product.v2ProductCategory,
           hits.transaction.transactionId
   FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([XXXXXX.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2016-04-1'), TIMESTAMP('2016-04-30')))
WHERE fullVisitorId IN
    ( SELECT fullVisitorId
     FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([XXXXXX.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2016-04-1'), TIMESTAMP('2016-04-30'))
     WHERE hits.product.v2ProductCategory CONTAINS 'Animals'
       AND hits.product.v2ProductName = 'Elephant'
       AND hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = '6'
     GROUP BY fullVisitorId)
  AND hits.product.v2ProductCategory CONTAINS 'Animals'
  AND hits.product.v2ProductName IS NOT NULL
  AND hits.product.v2ProductName !='Elephant'
  AND hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = '6'
GROUP BY other_purchased_products_sku,
         other_product_name,
         other_prod_category,
         trans_id,
         fullVisitorId
ORDER BY trans_id DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this is what you need:

```
SELECT
    a.fv fv,
    a.sku sku,
    a.name name,
    a.category category,
    a.qtd qtd,
    a.tid tid
FROM(
    SELECT
        fullvisitorid fv,
        visitid v,
        hits.product.productsku sku,
        hits.product.v2productname name,
        hits.product.v2productcategory category,
        COUNT(hits.product.productsku) qtd,
        hits.transaction.transactionid tid
    FROM (table_date_range([XXXXXXX.ga_sessions_], timestamp("20160501"), timestamp("20160501"))),
(table_date_range([XXXXXXXX.ga_sessions_intraday_], timestamp("20160501"), timestamp("20160501")))
    WHERE 1 = 1
and hits.ecommerceaction.action_type = '6'
GROUP EACH BY fv, v, sku, name, category, tid
) a
INNER JOIN EACH(
    SELECT
        fullvisitorid fv,
        visitid v,
        hits.product.productsku sku,
        hits.product.v2productname name,
        hits.product.v2productcategory category,
        hits.transaction.transactionid tid
    FROM (table_date_range([XXXXXXXX.ga_sessions_], timestamp("20160501"), timestamp("20160501"))),
(table_date_range([XXXXXXXX.ga_sessions_intraday_], timestamp("20160501"), timestamp("20160501")))
    WHERE 1 = 1
and hits.ecommerceaction.action_type = '6'
and lower(hits.product.v2productcategory) contains "animals"
and lower(hits.product.v2productname) contains "elephant"
    GROUP EACH BY fv, v, sku, name, category, tid
) b
on a.fv = b.fv and a.tid = b.tid
```

Breaking it down:

First the query group `b`:

```
SELECT
    fullvisitorid fv,
    visitid v,
    hits.product.productsku sku,
    hits.product.v2productname name,
    hits.product.v2productcategory category,
    hits.transaction.transactionid tid
FROM (table_date_range([XXXXXXXX.ga_sessions_], timestamp("20160501"), timestamp("20160501"))),
    (table_date_range([XXXXXXXX.ga_sessions_intraday_], timestamp("20160501"), timestamp("20160501")))
WHERE 1 = 1
    and hits.ecommerceaction.action_type = '6'
    and lower(hits.product.v2productcategory) contains "animals"
    and lower(hits.product.v2productname) contains "elephant"
GROUP EACH BY fv, v, sku, name, category, tid
```

This query first will retrieve the `fullvisitorids` and `transactionids` that you want with categories `animals` and names `elephant`.

Then in query group `a`:

```
SELECT
    fullvisitorid fv,
    visitid v,
    hits.product.productsku sku,
    hits.product.v2productname name,
    hits.product.v2productcategory category,
    COUNT(hits.product.productsku) qtd,
    hits.transaction.transactionid tid
FROM (table_date_range([XXXXXXX.ga_sessions_], timestamp("20160501"), timestamp("20160501"))),
(table_date_range([XXXXXXXX.ga_sessions_intraday_], timestamp("20160501"), timestamp("20160501")))
WHERE 1 = 1
    and hits.ecommerceaction.action_type = '6'
GROUP EACH BY fv, v, sku, name, category, tid
```

you retrieve all `fullvisitorids`, their `transactions` and the correspondent `products`.

With the inner join only the transactions of your interest remain (fullvisitors that in a given transaction bought in category "animals" and name "elephant").

I hope this helps. Any issues let me know,

Comment: Hi Will, thank you for solving the problem and for a quality explanation. Do you also know how I can add two additional columns. transaction_ga:date (YYYYMMDD), transaction_ga:isoWeek_number (1-52(3 if week 53 exist?) )?

Comment: just bring the fields `date` and `week(date)` inside each group and make the join also on those fields.

Comment: That worked too. Again thanks for your support on this.

Comment: Done Will. Could not find the button :)

Comment: Hi Will, Do you know how I can ensure that week(date) is producing week numbers ISO 8601 (week starts Monday)?

Comment: Just checked the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#datetimefunctions and looks like this is not possible =/

Comment: Hi Will. I came across this discussion. Do you think something along those lines would work? https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=208

Comment: Hi @MaartenBerge. Just tried here and looks like it worked! All I had to do was to bring date to the outer select and then select the date like so:
`INTEGER(STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(PARSE_UTC_USEC(a.date),"%V"))  date`
For what I tested the results were correct (used this site to confirm: http://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2016)

Comment: Yeah it works @Will. I added it as the last line in the first select and kept the rest:     `INTEGER(STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(PARSE_UTC_USEC(a.tdate),"%V")) iso8601_week_number` Now I have two week columns one with the US  week numbers (tweek) and one with iso8601 week numbers (iso8601_week_number). Just what I need. Cheers